# Performance problems when reading from a socket

Tags: r, sockets

The package that I have written to communicate with the BaseX XML-database (see [https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RBaseX](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RBaseX)) seems to be stable, the last month I haven't seen any errors. The only problem is the performance. 
Executing this query:

```
let $words := for $text in collection('IncidentRemarks/IncidentRemarks.csv')/csv/record/INC_RM
  return ft:tokenize($text)
return $words
```

takes about 48 ms. Reading the resulting 350000 bytes from the socket takes > 100 seconds.

I use this function to read from the socket:

```
str_receive = function(input, output, bin = FALSE) {
  if (missing(input)) input   <- self$get_socket()
  if (missing(output)) output <- raw(0)
  while ((rd <- readBin(input, what = "raw", n =1)) > 0) {
    if (rd == 0xff) rd <- readBin(input, what = "raw", n =1)
    output <- c(output, rd)
  }
  # The 'Full'-method embeds a \0 in the output
  if (!bin) ret <- strip_CR_NUL(output) %>% rawToChar()
  else ret <- output
  return(ret)
  }
```

The package uses R6. Since I haven't found a good method yet to profile R6-methods, I use the browser() to debug. It shows that the while-loop causes the delay. (And it is my guess that especially the `output <- c(output, rd)` is the main problem).
What is the best approach to speed up reading from the socket?

The most recent sourcecode for this package can be found at https://github.com/BenEngbers/RBaseX

Ben
PS. Please don't tell that I have to use 'C' or 'CPP'. I have always succeeded avoiding those languages ;-)

April 6,

I isolated the code that reads from the socket:

```
socket_reader <- function(socket_in) {
  string_read <- raw(0)
  while ((rd <- readBin(socket_in, what = "raw", n =1)) > 0) {
    if (rd == 0xff) rd <- readBin(socket_in, what = "raw", n =1)
    string_read <- c(string_read, rd)
  }
  return(string_read)
}
```

And replaced that code with :

```
socket_reader <- function(socket_in) {
  string_read <- raw(0)
  CONT <- TRUE
  Buf_Size <- 4096
  while (CONT) {
    read_buffer <- readBin(socket_in, what = "raw", n = Buf_Size)
    if (length(read_buffer) < Buf_Size) CONT <- FALSE
    string_read <- c(string_read, read_buffer)
  }
  string_read <- strip_FF(string_read)
  string_read <- string_read[-(length(string_read))] %>% as.raw()
  return(string_read)
}
```

This code should be a lot faster. The `strip_FF()` function removes (the) \0xFF bytes from string_read so both versions should give the same result.
Between the several read-operations however, I have to read a (1) statusbyte from the connection. A value of \0x00 means success, \0x01 means a failure.

My new version fails to read that statusbyte.

How can I read 1 byte from the connection and move the position in the connection?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

My assumption was that the function 'readLines' would be faster than 'readBin' and that's why I tried to apply that function. By the way, according to this article [Reading a complete file with R](https://gist.github.com/hadley/6353939), that assumption was not justified. I have now learned that readLines can only be used for reading character strings and not for reading binary data.